# How to create a ROWNUMBER column that always keeps a column of sequential numbers from 1 to N. The count of the column

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

In SQL Server, I am trying to create a column of sequential numbers to help me with my code. I am not sure how to create a column that is always populated with a sequential set of numbers starting from 1.

```
1
2
3
N

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS RowRankNumber FROM Statements WHERE RowRankNumber >= "+1+" AND RowRankNumber <= "+4+"", con);
```

Comment: What's wrong with `ROW_NUMBER`? You *can* use `IDENTITY` or a `SEQUENCE` to create a always ascending value at the `INSERT` point, however, there can be gaps in both, due to failing inserts, deleted rows, etc.

Comment: In Sql Server, I am just looking to force a column to always be in ascending order without any gaps. so when a row is deleted, you wont see 4, 6. you will instead see 4, 5.. Ill look into what you mentioned

Comment: So, to repeat myself, *"What's wrong with `ROW_NUMBER`?"*

Comment: can you define a row_number in the query without initializing it in the column. im just realizing. so i could say >= row(number) and <= row(number)

Comment: my query works fine when my column is populated but it doesn't work when its not. which was expected. Are you saying to create a column in sql server of type row_column, if so i will have to look that up because i have yet to find the syntax for that

Answer (score 1):

You need to use inner query to get the result. In your query the you can't use row_number in where clause. For example

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS RowRankNumber,* FROM Statements 
) x WHERE RowRankNumber >=1  AND RowRankNumber <=4
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this out